# To get the week number in a column using Python

Tags: python, date, datetime, week-number

I was trying to get this requirement where I want to have a column in my dataframe with week number, based on Days, Month an yr present in data.
Here is the below code-

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
s={'yr':[2014,2014,2014,2014,2015,2015,2015,2015],'Month':['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug'],'Days':[12,24,11,22,10,15,22,3]}
p=pd.DataFrame(data=s)
```

[image]

```
import datetime
p['week']=datetime.date(p['yr'], p['Month'], p['Days']).isocalendar().week

I am getting the below error-
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

I am not sure on how to resolve this error, I think I need to convert Month in numeric format too, how would be able to do this and get the week number in the date also?

Comment: does 'Days' represent the day of the month?

Comment: @FObersteiner yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line isn't as nice, but it works:

```
p['week'] = [datetime.datetime.strptime(str(p['yr'][i])+p['Month'][i]+str(p['Days'][i]), '%Y%b%d').isocalendar()[1] for i in range(len(p))]
```

Comment: consider using [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

Comment: The months are stored as a string, which (i think) pd.to_datetime can't handle.

Comment: try `pd.to_datetime(p['yr'].astype(str)+p['Month']+p['Days'].astype(str), format='%Y%b%d').dt.isocalendar().week` ;-)